# Exercise from "Methods of Homological Algebra" Gelfand

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, homological-algebra

I have to show that a map of complexes $f: A^{\bullet} \to B^{\bullet}$ in $Ab$ with $H^{n}(f)=0$  is not necessarily 0 in the derived category $D(\mathcal{A})$. To find this counterexample I'm given the two first rows of this diagram:

[image]

With $\pi_2 (1)=[2]$. I know that a morphism $f$ is $0$ in $D(\mathcal{A})$ iff exists a quasi-isomorphism  $s: B^{\bullet} \to C^{\bullet}$ such that $sf$ is homotopic to $0$.

I assume there is some quasi-isomorphism (qis) s and an homotopy $t$ such that $s_1=t\circ2$.

Now the part I'm not sure. The map $t: A^{\bullet}[1] \to C^{\bullet}$ must be an epimorphism since $H^{1}(s)=H(s_1)=H(t) \circ H(2)$, but $H^{2}(A^\bullet)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H^{2}(C^\bullet)=\mathbb{Z}$ hence we find a contradiction.

Is everything I'm assuming right?

Comment: Why does your third complex only have two nonzero terms?

Comment: Oops, good point. Is it true that in the derived category this wont matter much since the quasi isormorphism $s$ implies that the other terms have zero homology?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Objects in the derived category aren't well defined as complexes: you're drawing a picture in the category of chain complexes, not the derived category. The rest of the complex should certainly be a cyclic, but it needn't be zero.

Comment: This example seems unnecessarily complicated. You can replace $\mathbb{Z}_3$ with the trivial group in the example and it still gives a non-zero map in the derived category that induces the zero map on homology.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, derived categories are tricky.  I'll try this again  and if I don't succeed I'll ask for some hints.